# Using Ifelse in a dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

The data frame that I am using is

```
> df <- data.frame(Name=c("Joy","Jane","Jack","Jad"),M1=c(10,40,55,90))
> df
  Name M1
1  Joy 10
2 Jane 40
3 Jack 55
4  Jad 90

> df$Final <- ifelse(df$M1<=50,60,max(75,df$M1))
> df
  Name M1 Final
1  Joy 10    60
2 Jane 40    60
3 Jack 55    90
4  Jad 90    90
```

If the M1 value is less than or equal to 50 then I need 60 as my final value, while if the M1 value is greater than 50 then I need the maximumm(75,M1). In the case of Jack, M1 is 55, so I should get the max(75,55) which is 75. I think it is giving me the max of entire M1 column. How to avoid this?

Desired output

```
  Name M1 Final
1  Joy 10    60
2 Jane 40    60
3 Jack 55    75
4  Jad 90    90
```

Comment: pmax(df$M1, c(60, 75)[1 + (df$M1 > 50)])

Comment: like Imo says, just change `max` to `pmax` and you have it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about :

```
ifelse(df$M1<=50,60,ifelse(df$M1>75,df$M1,75))
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `pmax` instead of `max`:

```
ifelse(df$M1 <= 50, 60, pmax(75, df$M1))
```

From the help file, `pmax` takes

> one or more vectors (or matrices) as arguments and return(s) a single vector giving the ‘parallel’ maxima ... of the vectors. The first element of the result is the maximum ... of the first elements of all the arguments, the second element of the result is the maximum ... of the second elements of all the arguments and so on.

Thus the third argument to `ifelse`, the "else" value, is the pairwise maximum of 75 (recycled as many times as needed) and the values of df$M1.

Comment: Nice one.  Done without `ifelse()` with `replace(pmax(75, df$M1), df$M1 <= 50, 60)` Not sure if there's any efficiency benefit though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just came across the `replace` function today. I have it on my list of "look into further" functions, which continues to grow.

Comment: @Richard I'm thinking an efficient way might involve findInterval (to avoid testing two inequalities): `s = split(seq_along(m), findInterval(m, c(50, 75)))[1:2];
m[unlist(s)] = rep(c(60,75), lengths(s))
`

Answer (score 3):

You're essentially describing a rule like...

- up to 50, replace with 60
- up to 75, replace with 75
- up to x, replace with y
- ...

If we put the rule into a data.frame, it is more explicit and probably allows for more efficient derivation of the results (instead of computing many inequalities). Here are two ways:

**`findInterval`**

```
m = data.frame(up_to = c(50, 75), replace_with = c(60, 75))

df$Final = df$M1
r = m$replace_with[ findInterval(df$M1, m$up_to) + 1L ]
df$Final = replace(df$M1, !is.na(r), na.omit(r))
```

**`data.table` rolling joins**

```
library(data.table)    
setDT(df)

m = data.table(up_to = c(50, 75), replace_with = c(60, 75))

df[, Final := M1]
r = m[df, on=c(up_to = "M1"), roll=-Inf][!is.na(replace_with), Final := replace_with]$Final
df[, Final := r]
```

Comment: Would it be more efficient than `c(rep(60, 50),rep(75, 25), 76:max(df$M1))[df$M1]`?

Comment: @HubertL Yeah, I like that idea; it should work well if M1 is an integer vector with a small range. The extension to a general rule (stored in a structure like `m`) is not obvious, though. For example, there are edge cases like if `max(df$M1)` happens to be less than 75; and we should also be able to take advantage of `min(df$M1)`, I guess (though I'm not sure how to code it up). If you can figure it out, you could add it to your answer or post a separate one.

Answer (score 0):

If `d$M1` only contains positive and non null `integer`s, using a look-up might be more efficient:

```
lookup <-  c(rep(60, 50),rep(75, 25), 76:max(df$M1,76))
lookup[df$M1]
```

If it contains also negative or null `integer`s :

```
lookup <-  c(rep(60, 50-min(df$M1)+1),rep(75, 25), 76:max(df$M1,76))
lookup[df$M1-min(df$M1)+1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `dplyr` and `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Final = ifelse(M1<=50,60,max(75,M1)))
```