# How to replace multiple values at once

Tags: r

I would like to replace different values in a vector with specific other values at once.

In the problem I'm working through:

- 1 should be replaced with 2,
- 2 with 4,
- 3 with 6,
- 4 with 8,
- 5 with 1,
- 6 with 3,
- 7 with 5 and
- 8 with 7.

So that:

```
x <- c(4, 2, 0, 7, 5, 7, 8, 9)
x
[1] 4 2 0 7 5 7 8 9
```

would be converted to:

```
[1] 8 4 0 5 1 5 7 9
```

after the replacements.

I have tried using:

```
x[x == 1] <- 2
x[x == 2] <- 4
```

and so on, but that results in 1 getting replaced with 7.

What is the simplest solution to this problem without using any packages?

Comment: limited to single digit numbers, but interesting: `type.convert(strsplit(chartr(paste(1:8, collapse = ''), 
                paste(c(2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7), collapse = ''), 
                paste(x, collapse = '')), 
         '')[[1]])`

Comment: See e.g. "a more general approach" in [the accepted answer in the first link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16228315/1851712).

Comment: The 'indexing a named vector' approach in the [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7548031/1851712) would in your case be `setNames(c(0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9), 0:9)[as.character(x)]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A possible solution using `match`:

```
old <- 1:8
new <- c(2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7)

x[x %in% old] <- new[match(x, old, nomatch = 0)]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > x
> [1] 8 4 0 5 1 5 7 9
> ```

What this does:

- Create two vectors: `old` with the values that need to be replaced and `new` with the corresponding replacements.
- Use `match` to see where values from `x` occur in `old`. Use `nomatch = 0` to remove the `NA`'s. This results in an indexvector of the position in `old` for the `x` values
- This index vector can then be used to index `new`.
- Only assign the values from `new` to the positions of `x` that are present in `old`: `x[x %in% old]`

Comment: Or `c(new, x)[match(x, c(old, x))]` as described here: [Multiple replacement in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16228315/1851712)

Answer (score 8):

If one can define conversion pair for all values then converting to `factor` and then back to integer can be an option.

```
old <- 0:9
new <- c(0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9)

as.integer(as.character(factor(x, old, new)))
# [1] 8 4 0 5 1 5 7 9
```