# Expand variable labels in table

Tags: r

I have a column in a data frame that looks like this:

```
    Category      X        Y
        M         45       56
        F         45       54
        O         23       56
```

I want to replace M, F and O with Male, Female and Other.

Comment: ok.. this should not be too hard. What have you tried and wasn't working as expected?

Comment: I used df[1,1] = Male, df[2,1]= female and df[3,1]= other, but I'd like to know if this is possible in a single line of code

Comment: have you tried solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50898623/how-to-replace-multiple-values-at-once ?

Comment: Does this work? `df[, 1] <- c("Male", "Female", "Other")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
Category<-c("M","F","O")
X<-c(45,45,23)
Y<-c(56,54,56)
df<-data.frame(Category, X, Y)
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {gsub("M", "Male", x)}))
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {gsub("F", "Female", x)}))
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {gsub("O", "Other", x)}))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Category = recode(Category, "M" = "Male", "F" = "Female", "O" = "Other"))
```