# Replacing values by cell index across all columns of dataframe R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, purrr

looking for answers similar to these posts; [R: Replace multiple values in multiple columns of dataframes with NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768305/r-replace-multiple-values-in-multiple-columns-of-dataframes-with-na) ; [Multiple replacement in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228160/multiple-replacement-in-r/16228315#16228315)

My dataframe `my.df` contains `NAs`.

```
dput(my.df)
structure(list(`AICAR (GDSC1:1001)_GDSC1` = c(10.1253052794007, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.3362273693641, NA, NA, NA), `vinblastine (GDSC1:1004)_GDSC1` = c(-5.56689193211021, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -3.49808657768651, NA, NA, -5.7323006155361
), `cisplatin (GDSC1:1005)_GDSC1` = c(3.20680858158152, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `cytarabine (GDSC1:1006)_GDSC1` = c(-1.29089026889862, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `docetaxel (GDSC1:1007)_GDSC1` = c(-9.21190331946225, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.51430196744496), `methotrexate (GDSC1:1008)_GDSC1` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -4.96153980941858, NA, NA, NA), `gefitinib (GDSC1:1010)_GDSC1` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -4.65609368323825), `navitoclax (GDSC1:1011)_GDSC1` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `vorinostat (GDSC1:1012)_GDSC1` = c(-0.1834250603902, 
1.80666265545084, 0.503152683902549, 1.78569632218743, NA, 1.01934567070847, 
0.321867836558935, NA, 2.18003424956055, 0.143794452798708)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I get the cell location of each NA using `idx <- my.df %>% lapply(., function(x) which(is.na(x)))`
Convert these `NAs` to 0 by `my.df %>% mutate_if(.,is.numeric, ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))`  before I calculate correlations.
Now how can I return the `NAs` into their dedicated cells based on the`idx`?

I recon `loops, tidy, purrr` or something similar can do this fast? Would be great if a match could be done between the column names of `my.df` and the names of `idx` for quality control in the code.

Thanks!

Comment: do not use `lapply`. use `idx <- is.na(my.df)` Then do whatever you want to `my.df` Once done you can do `is.na(my.df) <-idx`

Comment: or... use `cor(..., type = 'pairwise.complete.obs')` to calculate the correlation and leave your data unaffected? Your correlation is likely biased after imputation, unless you have pre-knowledge that NA's are in fact 0's in which case they can should be replaced and not returned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I do the first alternative I get `Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value, value = NA) : 
  unsupported matrix index in replacement`

Comment: Could you give an example of what is the expected output of  'how can I return the NAs into their dedicated cells based on their idx'

Comment: if you consider the example above, I turns NAs in the cells to 0, I do some stuff with the data but the location of cells is still the same. so now I want to insert NAs back to their original cells.